# How to display EditText input of word real-time

Tags: java, android

I try display EditText input of word real-time,

I use the code of

```
    input.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() 
    {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            int unicodeChar = event.getUnicodeChar();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf((char)unicodeChar), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }
    });
```

but,the method only display numbers, English characters or other characters can not be displayed...

So where is the problem?

Comment: This may be a silly question, but does the EditText end up with letters and other characters in it? I just want to make sure there it isn't just an inputType set on the EditText?

Comment: Because I want to use this value as the conditional, so I have to get input characters EditText